# What is the difference between reg and wire after synthesizing?

Tags: verilog, synthesis

Assuming i have these two codes:

```
module wire_example( a, b, y);
  input a, b;
  output y;

  wire a, b, y;

  assign y = a & b;

endmodule
```

and the second one is:

```
module reg_combo_example( a, b, y);
input a, b;
output y;

reg   y;
wire a, b;

always @ ( a or b)
begin   
  y = a & b;
end

endmodule
```

my question is what is the difference in the net list, both of them will have an gate, but will the module with `reg y` will have a flip flop or a latch to hold the data while `wire y` won't have any latch?

Answer (score 9):

Neither of your examples will contain any latches or flip-flops. The `always` block in your second example is combinational, not sequential (if it were to synthesize a latch, what clock would control that latch?). You have to use a `reg` type for `y` simply because it appears on the left side of an assignment statement inside an `always` block. Many people consider this a disadvantage of Verilog, which is hard to argue with. In VHDL, a `signal` type would be used instead of both `wire` and `reg`, removing the confusion.

Comment: ....  which is why you use SystemVerilog and just declare a "logic"

Comment: will using a reg instead of wire result in slower circuit?

Answer (score 1):

`wire`:

It is a net which represents the connections between components. It is used for continuous assignments, that is,  `wire` has its value continuously driven on it by outputs of the devices connected to them.

`reg`:

It is used for procedural assignments. `reg` always doesn’t mean a flop/register. `reg` can also keep its value until another value is placed into the registers.